# How to get file size in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I'm using following code to upload a file submitted through a form. How can I get file size before uploading it? I want the max file size to be 20mb.

```
$file = $data->getFileName();
if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
    $uploadManager = $this->get('probus_upload.upload_manager.user_files');
    if ($newFileName = $uploadManager->move($file)) {
        $data->setFileName(basename($newFileName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Oldskool is correct. However if you want to retrieve the exact file size after it has been uploaded, you can use the following:

```
$fileSize = $file->getClientSize();
```

Another solution would be to change maximum size of upload file in php.ini. The following will echo the current file size limit.

```
echo $file->getMaxFilesize();
```

To get form errors, you should validate the form and print any errors if the validation fails.

```
//include at the top of controller
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$form = $this->createForm(new FileType(), $file);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    //store data
    $data = "stored successfully";
    $statusCode = 200;
} else {
    //return errors if form is invalid
    $data = $form->getErrors();
    $statusCode = 500;
}

return new Response($data, $statusCode);
```

Comment: is there any way to display error message in form if user selected file if size greater than 20mb?

Comment: it gives error

The controller must return a response (Object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator) given).

Comment: Your controller is expected to return Response object. So you can just create it with response data. Check the edit

Answer (score 3):

Simply annotate the File object in your Entity with the `maxSize` option:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "20M"
 * )
 */
protected $userFiles;
```

Also see the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize) on this for further details.

Comment: is there any way to display error message in form if user selected file if size greater than 20mb?

Comment: this is my form to create file field

->add('fileName', 'file', array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'required' => $obj->getId() === null ? true : false,
        'label' => 'Upload File'
        ))

Comment: I think that if you use the FormBuilder with a file input, it should come along with the hidden `MAX_FILE_SIZE` field, which should alert you if the file is too large. Also see the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) on file uploads.